# Yahoo Pipes: Extracting image from RSS description

Tags: regex, rss, pipe, yahoo

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and searched all of Stackoverflow and did research on Google but I havent figured it out exactly. Thank you for you help in advance.

The incoming RSS has image(s) in the **description** and I would like to extract the image link and store it into the "media.url"

See image of my pipe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50P94.jpg